# Read all the cell values from an Excel range in C#

Tags: c#

Suppose I have range from E2 to E16. How do I read values from cells E2 to E16?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try somethinfg like this. it should work

U can specify ur range as u wish inside.

```
this.openFileDialog1.FileName = "*.xls";
  if (this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(
         openFileDialog1.FileName, 0, true, 5,
          "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false,
          0, true); 
     Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;
     Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
     for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
     {
     Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A"+i.ToString(), "J" + i.ToString());
     System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
     string[] strArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);
     }
}

string[] ConvertToStringArray(System.Array values)
{ 

// create a new string array
string[] theArray = new string[values.Length];

// loop through the 2-D System.Array and populate the 1-D String Array
 for (int i = 1; i <= values.Length; i++)
  {
   if (values.GetValue(1, i) == null)
    theArray[i-1] = "";
  else
   theArray[i-1] = (string)values.GetValue(1, i).ToString();
  }

  return theArray;
}
```

Comment: but if i have a fixed range already i am passing from cell and two cell to a function say fromcell = A3 and Tocell=A8 and i need to have the values from A3 to A8

Comment: then u need to remove the for loop and give the range  directly in the code somthing as follows 

Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("E2", "E16");

Comment: what is the namespace i should use to get ConvertToStringArray

Comment: ConvertToStringArray is a local method and is not a library method. So, you will have to include it in your code and then reference it using whatever namespace you place it in (presumably you will have it be a private static method in whatever class you are reading your excel file in)

Answer (score 5):

Another Alternative approach. Positng as a spearate answer because it wil be give less space for confusion.

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbook wbook = null;

Excel.Worksheet wsheet = null;

Excel.Range range = null;

app.Visible = false;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

string filepath = inputFile1.Value.ToString();

if (filepath != "")

{

wbook = app.Workbooks.Open(filepath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

Missing.Value, Missing.Value);



string currentSheet = "Sheet1";

wsheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wbook.Worksheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

range = wsheet.get_Range("B6", "H20");

System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value2;

valueArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);



if (app != null)

{

app.Workbooks.Close();

app.Quit();

}

app = null;

wsheet = null;

range = null;

string[] ConvertToStringArray(System.Array values)
{ 

// create a new string array
string[] theArray = new string[values.Length];

// loop through the 2-D System.Array and populate the 1-D String Array
 for (int i = 1; i <= values.Length; i++)
  {
   if (values.GetValue(1, i) == null)
    theArray[i-1] = "";
  else
   theArray[i-1] = (string)values.GetValue(1, i).ToString();
  }

  return theArray;
}
```