# parse excel file best practise

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am facing an issue in parsing excel file. My file has more than 5000 rows. When I parse it, its taking ages I wanted to ask if there's any better way to do so.

```
public static List<List<List<string>>> ExtractData(string filePath)
{
    List<List<List<string>>> Allwork = new List<List<List<string>>>();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);


    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet in workBook.Worksheets)
    {

        List<List<string>> Sheet = new List<List<string>>();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range usedRange = sheet.UsedRange;

        //Iterate the rows in the used range
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in usedRange.Rows)
        {
            List<string> Rows = new List<string>();
            String[] Data = new String[row.Columns.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Data[i] = row.Cells[1, i + 1].Value2.ToString();
                    Rows.Add(row.Cells[1, i + 1].Value2.ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                    Rows.Add("     ");

                }
            }
            Sheet.Add(Rows);
        }
        Allwork.Add(Sheet);

    }
    excelApp.Quit();
    return Allwork;
}
```

This is my code.

Comment: What kind of program is this in? ASP.NET or Windows Forms?

Comment: its windows forms. By the way does it really matter?

Comment: Absolutely. It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Thanks was not aware of that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are reading one cell at a time, this is very costly and inefficient try reading a range of cells.

Simple example below

```
Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A"+i.ToString(), "J" + i.ToString());

System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;

string[] strArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);
```

A link to basic example
[Read all the cell values from a given range in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627343/read-all-the-cell-values-from-a-given-range-in-excel)

Comment: how can I convert myvalues to string[,] or list<list<string>> ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not use interop, but odbc connection for getting excel data. This will allow you to treat excel file as database and use sql statements to read needed data.

Answer (score 0):

If that's an option, and if your tables have a simple structure,  I would suggest to try exporting the file to .csv and applying simple string processing logic.

You might also want to try out the Igos's sugestion.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use something like the [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) library to directly read the .xlsx file, not going through the Excel interop.