# System.InvalidCastException Double to String

Tags: c#, excel, casting

The following code opens an Excel spreadsheet and goes through it cell by cell.  The `Console.WriteLine` call is for checking that it is working correctly.

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"\Extracts\Test.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
rw = range.Rows.Count;
cl = range.Columns.Count;

for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
{
    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl; cCnt++)
    {
        string str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        Console.WriteLine("Row:", str.ToString());
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> System.InvalidCastException 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.'

This refers to line:

```
string str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
```

I am aware that there is another question with the same error but that solution doesn't appear to work in this case.

Help appreciated thanks.

Comment: I'm posting this comment in case anyone else is trying to do something similar and coming up against problems.  If you want to parse every cell and get the value for each, this works: `Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, cCnt];`
                        `string cellValue = rng.Value.ToString();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

don't cast the double value. Simply call [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad(v=vs.110).aspx) to get

> The string representation of the value of this instance.

```
string str = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
```

EDIT:

calling `ToString` on a string is not necessary, since it is already a string.
You can simply write it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Row:", str);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is now working but the value str appears to be blank, so I am obviously doing something wrong (new to c#), any idea how I can get it to output the value of each cell to the console?  There is data in the sheet.

Comment: Also, with that solution, the part `str.ToString()` is useless: just print `str` to the console.

Comment: @davidjwest I don't have much knowledge about Excel interop. But it seems that you have a range of values. You should research for "get all values from excel range." May be [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627343/read-all-the-cell-values-from-an-excel-range-in-c-sharp) can help